# Unity3D what is the difference between NetworkClient.Connect vs. Network.Connect?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

Good day,

I'm new to Unity Networking Server/Client.

I want to build a game that has a lobby then players can enter to the room set ready then start the game.

I want to know how can I start networking this client to server.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome, please try to make your question as clear as possible, as you are asking about difference between 2 methods, and "how to"...

Comment: Try the NetworkLobbyManager (not so bad official example on asset store)

Comment: Hi, FLX.

Until now i can't find my answer.

Comment: Hi, @FLX.

Until now i can't find my answer.

This is what I want to happen in my system.
A server that can create multiple rooms and let the client join.
wait the room to be filled then start the lobby to the server.
There's no multiplayer will be happen, all the clients that's connected to that room will just playing at the same time but in different scenes then sent the data to the server. (lets say 10 players playing flappy bird then send the score data to the sever for each player then the server will check who's player is out/dead). What function need to use?

Comment: You won't find "THE" solution or function that will solve everything for you. This is programming. Split your problem in multiple questions and solve them one by one. You can use networklobbymanager to regroup players in a room, then it's up to you. You are not forced to "do multiplayer" (i.e. sync transforms) once you're in the game scene.

Comment: ok thanks for the feedback @FLX much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Network.Connect is from the older Unity API, and was replaced by NetworkClient.Connect. They are part of the [High Level Networking API of Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetUsingHLAPI.html).
Please have a look at this example for a step by step into multiplayer: [Unity multiplayer example](https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking)

For a lower level usage of the networking, you have [`NetworkTransport` class](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkTransport.html).

Comment: I thought Network.Connect was from the obsolete networking system ?

Comment: Correct, I confused it with NetworkTransport... thank you !

Comment: I don't know where to start.

Networkmanager
NetworkLobbyManager
NetworkServer/NetworkClient
NetworkTransport
MasterServer?

is this all different?

thnx

Comment: Hello Ryan, yes it is all different, like FLX indicated, please ask a new question specifically. As a reminder your question was "Unity3D what is the difference between NetworkClient.Connect vs. Network.Connect?"